# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using services but it crashes when i close the application on getExtraString()

Here is the code

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent startingIntent,int flags,int startid)
    {
        msg = startingIntent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

The application crashes on msg=startingIntent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

Here is the code where the services are started in BroadcastReceiver

```
 if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            String name = getContactName(context, number);
            Intent speechIntent = new Intent();
            speechIntent.setClass(context, TTSServices.class);
            speechIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            if (name == null) {
                speechIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE","Phone call from "+ number);
                Toast.makeText(context, number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                speechIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "Phone call From "+name);
                Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            context.startService(speechIntent);
        }
```

Comment: You have null intent in 2nd line, 2nd window

Comment: You seem to be missing a question here as well as the full logcat exception